# connect to a bluetooth headset on a pc

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, bluetooth, headset

I have a vibrating headset, that vibrates on incoming calls from a mobile-device.
I would like to connect to this headset with my PC, and send it the "incoming call signal" as if it received a call.

How can this be done by command-line or .net (C#) ?

Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I have found that might help you out is the [32Feet library](http://inthehand.com/content/32feet.aspx) there discussion about the subject of your question can be found [here](http://32feet.codeplex.com/discussions/topics/5276/bluetooth-microsoft)
hope it helps!